# Redundant notice for already reviewed suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, spam-detection

[This suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/54615) is already rejected, but notice says “please review carefully”:

> [image: review rejected]

This is completely redundant in this case and should be removed. 
Also I’m not sure about the needing to know that this edit has identified as possible spam after being reviewed.

Comment: About the actual spam notice: that was added because I made an edit through the same IP as the one in your screenshot, and got insta-banned. The real bug here is that the spam notice should not show up on already-reviewed reviews, only pending reviews.

Comment: Though you can disagree that it's a bug: it was a way for me to prove to others that I was insta-banned in case I needed to do my edits over stages and/or use a VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the notice there is very much by-design. It shows to other users in the future that they were warned about potential spam and that they should be reviewing more carefully, providing additional context to how the review task was seen when it was completed. It's kind of like rereading your test after it's been graded. You don't go through removing all the calls to action just because you can't actually complete the test anymore. The review task will always appear as it appeared for the reviewers.

Comment: Review audits looks differ before and after review.

Comment: Review audits are a completely different beast that are identified as "this was an audit" after-the-fact. In that situation you're faced with the choice of continuing to display it as originally seen and being extremely confusing but it doesn't clearly identify *why* someone passed/failed, or displaying its actual state to provide some clarity. The original state would be useful to other users, the actual state would be useful to the user who reviewed. Regular reviews do not have two different states, though.

Comment: So maybe worth to add "regular" word into last sentence of your answer?

Comment: Your answer only addresses the case where the notice is added while the edit is pending. Sometimes, the notice is added later, after the edit is already reviewed, such as the case in the comments on the question. The presence of this notice doesn't mean that they were warned about spam.